# Caching impression counts to avoid mysql inserts

Tags: mysql, php, memcached

We currently get a LOT of mySQL inserts/updates on duplicate daily (millions) and we're looking at speeding up the application by using some form of counter with memcached and then clearing it on intervals with a cron.

Is this possible? What happens if 2 people hit at the exact same millisecond? Will the counter still go up twice or will it only increment once? What is the best way to handle such a write heavy database?

Comment: Please show actual SQL statement(s) and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  You mention "milliseconds"; what datatype is involved wherein that is relevant?  And are you expecting uniqueness of ms values?